# How to send email with an image attachment with Qt?

Tags: qt, email, qtnetwork

I have to send an image or video to other person trough email. I initially tried with QAxObject with outlook, but it is not OS independent. I want to know how to create and send an email with Qt with option of an attachement. Is QSSLSocket is a good way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt itself doesn't provide an SMTP client. You need to use a third party library. There is at least one Qt-based SMTP client implementation, in [QxtNetwork module](http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/tip/qxtsmtp.html).

Comment: thank you. need a small suggestion . shall i use this QxtSMTP module or other third party lib ..? because i have to send mail with attachments..

Comment: @Wagmare It is up to you. If you wish to use the Qxt code, I suggest you have a look at [this pull request](http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/pull-request/42/smtp-reposnse-parser-rewritten-as-separate/diff) and possibly include those changes in your local copy of Qxt, since it's a bug that affects SMTP.